# Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page doesn't work

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 4.2.0 and I can't display the shipping fees on the cart page.
However, the option "Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page" is checked in the Woocommerce > settings > shipping.

[image][image]

Here's my child theme (Storefront) cart-totals.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart totals
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.6
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<div class="cart_totals <?php echo ( WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping() ) ? 'calculated_shipping' : ''; ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' ); ?>

    <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon, false ) ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        
        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) :
            $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
            $estimated_text  = WC()->customer->is_customer_outside_base() && ! WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping()
                    ? sprintf( ' <small>' . __( '(estimated for %s)', 'woocommerce' ) . '</small>', WC()->countries->estimated_for_prefix( $taxable_address[0] ) . WC()->countries->countries[ $taxable_address[0] ] )
                    : '';

            if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                        <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->label ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </table>


    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' ); ?>

</div>

<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your template appears to have _removed_ the part that is responsible for showing this. Compare it to the original template of that name in the woocommerce plugin’s template folder, you can see what is needed in there.

Comment: Thanks ! indeed the part about shipping is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your template file misses the shipping part. Simply add it from the original `cart-totals.php` template like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart totals
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.6
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<div class="cart_totals <?php echo ( WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping() ) ? 'calculated_shipping' : ''; ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' ); ?>

    <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon, false ) ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php elseif ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' ) ) : ?>

            <tr class="shipping">
                <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator(); ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) :
            $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
            $estimated_text  = WC()->customer->is_customer_outside_base() && ! WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping()
                    ? sprintf( ' <small>' . __( '(estimated for %s)', 'woocommerce' ) . '</small>', WC()->countries->estimated_for_prefix( $taxable_address[0] ) . WC()->countries->countries[ $taxable_address[0] ] )
                    : '';

            if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                        <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->label ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </table>


    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' ); ?>

</div>

<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes of course, just did. thanks for your help. Do you have an idea on how I could move the "Return to shop"  after the cart-totals, but only on mobile layout ? Thanks

Comment: I have posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525610/how-to-move-the-return-to-shop-after-the-cart-totals-on-cart-page