# How to move the "Return to shop" after the cart-totals on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to move the "Return to shop" after the cart-totals, on the mobile cart page, but before the "checkout" button.

Is that possible? Maybe hook it to ̀`<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' ); ?>`  in `cart-totals.php` if possible, but how to unhook it because it is hardcoded in the file cart.php:

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">
<a class="button wc-backward return-to-shop-cart-wholesale" href="/wholesale-ordering/">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Return to pro shop', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
    <a class="button wc-backward return-to-shop-cart-retail" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Return to shop', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
        <?php
        /**
         * Cart collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
    ?>
</div>
```

Also, can I do it only for mobile layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the follwoing:
first hide the 'Return to Shope' with this css,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.woocommerce-cart .return-to-shop { display: none !important; }
}
```

We use @media and '600px' to target only mobile devices.

Then add that button before the 'checkout',

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals', 'isnert_shop_back_button' );
function isnert_shop_back_button(){
<div class="cart-collaterals">
<a class="button wc-backward return-to-shop-cart-wholesale" href="/wholesale-ordering/">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Return to pro shop', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        </a>
        <a class="button wc-backward return-to-shop-cart-retail" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Return to shop', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        </a>
            <?php
            /**
             * Cart collaterals hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
             * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
        ?>
    </div>
    }
```

I just used the code you have to display the button 'Return TO SHope' but inside the function isnert_shop_back_button() you can place anything you want.

Try it and let me know what happen.